# Javascript object not removing id destroying calculating form

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, load

The code is now up and running however the delete part of this code does not work. The delete part should remove the given id from the object so that it is not included in the calculation once that id and its information is loaded out. However it doesn't it still keeps it in the calculation. I have tried several solutions around this provided by the community but nothing has worked. Anybody got any ideas.

```
var productIds = {} 
function product_analysis(address, id, box) {
    productIds[id] = true; // store all id's as the totals are calculated
    if (box.checked) {

      $('#product_' + box.alt).load(address);

    }
    else {

      $('#product_' + box.alt).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html');
      (delete productIds[id]);

    }
    document.getElementById('product_quantity_PRI_' + box.alt).value = box.value;


};

function product_totals(id) {
    productIds[id] = true; // store all id's as the totals are calculated
    var quantity = $('product_quantity_' + id).value;
    var price = $('product_price_' + id).value;
    var duration = $('product_duration_' + id).value;
    var dives = $('product_dives_' + id).value;
    var hire = $('product_hire_' + id).value;

    Number($('product_price_total_' + id).value = price * quantity);
    Number($('product_duration_total_' + id).value = duration * quantity);
    Number($('product_dives_total_' + id).value = dives * quantity);
    Number($('product_hire_total_' + id).value = hire * quantity);
    function $(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    } 

    var totalPriceTotal = 0;
    var totalDurationTotal = 0;
    var totalDivesTotal = 0;
    var totalHireTotal = 0;
    for (var id in productIds) {
        // multiply by 1 to make sure it's a number
        totalPriceTotal += $('product_price_total_' + id).value*1;
        totalDurationTotal += $('product_duration_total_' + id).value*1;
        totalDivesTotal += $('product_dives_total_' + id).value*1;
        totalHireTotal += $('product_hire_total_' + id).value*1;
    }
    $('GT_total_price').value = totalPriceTotal;
    $('GT_total_duration').value = totalDurationTotal;
    $('GT_total_dives').value = totalDivesTotal;
    $('GT_total_hire').value = totalHireTotal;

    function $(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where/how are those two functions called?  It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing more.

Comment: Also, that "$" function you define (twice) in "product_totals()" is somewhat perverted, given that you're using jQuery elsewhere.

Comment: The first function 'product_analysis(address, id, box)' is called onClick by the options on the page.

The second function 'function product_totals(id)' is called when the product loaded in in the first function has finished loading <script type="text/javascript">
product_totals('PRI_<?php the_ID(); ?>');
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You mention in comments that the second function is called

> ...when the product loaded in the first function has finished loading...

This is just a wild guess, but without seeing more of your code, it seems your `delete` is happening *after* the `.load()`, but not in a callback. Depending on how you've arranged things, the deletion may therefore be happening *after* the `product_totals(id)` call. So I'd suggest rearranging as follows:

```
 $('#product_' + box.alt)
   .load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html', function(){
     delete productIds[id];
     product_totals(id);
   });
```

Comment: Seems like a definite possibility.

Comment: The script is loaded in in the ajax load at the bottom of its code as so   <script type="text/javascript">
product_totals('PRI_<?php the_ID(); ?>');
</script>

Comment: Robin, what do you mean by "at the bottom of its code"? Do you mean at the bottom of the page?

Comment: THe bottom of the page that is loaded in via jquery

Comment: Are you loading into a DIV a page that has its own HTML, HEAD, BODY, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're doing here but it's also hard to get the delete operator wrong. Put an alert on productIds before and after the delete and I doubt you'll see the deleted key in the object.

Point is though that there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do - could you describe the operation in english?

Comment: Yes, there is probably a far better way. I am not native to coding so go easy on me. It is a booking form. There are options on the left that load corresponding products on the right via Jquery load. These loaded in items contain the price, duration, dives and hire fields of that product. They are then multiplied by the quantity assigned to the products when the option was selected. Then all added up in the object to give a total price, total duration etc..... Now rather than have me ravit on take a look http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training/ >> click on beginners

Comment: Not meant as a criticism, just that generally if you explain the intent you're providing the context to get a better answer.

Comment: @Robin: You seem to have some IE issues (don't we all), can't help further right now as I'm stuck with IE at work sorry. Ken's suggestion seems solid though.

Comment: I tried it with no effect,  but maybe we are looking at this the wrong way. At the moment product IDs are being referenced when calculating. Since the script has been failing because the IDs it referenced in the object may no longer exist. So what if instead the reference of ID's on the right hand side was made into a different function right before the adding up process. Now how would one do that? Many Thanks

Comment: Robin, if you think they're pertinent, you should distill your comments here and underneath the original question, and add them to the text of the question itself.